# Should I base64 encode the pickle to send over network/store into db?

Tags: python, base64, pickle

Pickle is a way to serialize the python object.

Suppose I want to send this over the network or store in a database, then can I send/store (respectively) the pickle value or do I need to base64 encode the pickle value?

Comment: A pickled object contains binary data, including zero bytes.  If you have a path that can't handle arbitrary binary data, then you'll need to encode it.  NOTE, however, that pickle is not a particularly good serialization format.  It is Python only, and the format has changed a few times.  JSON or XML may be better choices.

Comment: So you mean json.dump for example? In that case there is need for base64?

Comment: Right, `json.dumps` is already encoded, and it is a format that can be read by other languages.  However, that requires you to convert your object into a form that JSON likes, meaning lists and dicts.  If you can do that, it's a better way, in my opinion.

Answer (score 1):

JSON representations are strings. But even when I have JSON-serialized strings that contain Unicode characters that are not in the printable ASCII character set range, Python chooses a representation of these characters that are in the ASCII-printable range by default (*ensure_ascii=True* is the default value for the `json.dumps` call). For example:

```py
print(json.dumps('圣诞节\n\000'));
```

Prints:

```
"\u5723\u8bde\u8282\n\u0000"
```

There is nothing in the above serialized representation that requires special encoding. Now the issue is whether the object that you wish to serialize requires special encoding. For example, if the object has an attribute that is of type `decimal.Decimal`, which is not one of the supported JSON-serializable types, you would want to store the the string representation of this attribute.

For example:

```py
from decimal import Decimal
import json

class MyClass:
    def __init__(self, a: int, b: Decimal):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b

    def __repr__(self):
        return f'a = {self.a}, b = {self.b}'

    def serialize(self):
        return json.dumps({'a': self.a, 'b': str(self.b)})

    @classmethod
    def deserialize(cls, s):
        state = json.loads(s)
        return cls(state['a'], Decimal(state['b']))

obj1 = MyClass(3, Decimal('7.93'))
print('obj1:', obj1)
saved_state = obj1.serialize()
print('Saved state:', saved_state)
obj2 = MyClass.deserialize(saved_state)
print('obj2:', obj2)
```

Prints:

```
obj1: a = 3, b = 7.93
Saved state: {"a": 3, "b": "7.93"}
obj2: a = 3, b = 7.93
```

**Note**

If you named your methods `__getstate__` (instead of `serialize`) and `__setstate__` (instead of `deserialize`) and made the latter a regular instance method rather than a class method, then the class would also be compatible with the `pickle` module, though you need to think about whether you would want to use the standard pickling methodology for when you do not need to send the object across the wire or have it saved in a database or don't need the data-representation stability.